# If $T$ is a linear transformation and $\exists v\,\, T^2v\neq0, \,\,T^3v=0$, what is $\dim\operatorname{span}\left\{v, Tv, T^2v\right\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I am preparing for the GRE math subject test.
Here is the problem

## Problem

$T: V\to V$ is a linear transformation, there exists some $v\in V$ such that $T^2v\neq 0, T^3 v= 0$.
Let $S = \operatorname{span}\{v, Tv, T^2v\}$

True or False:

Claim 1. $Ts \neq s$ for any $s\neq 0$ and $s\in S$

Claim 2. $\dim(S) = 3$

## My thinking

It seems that $S$ is like a subspace generated by a Jordan block, so I guess Claim 2 is correct.
If $S$ is a Jordan block, I guess $\{v, Tv, T^2v\}$ is a basis for $S$ and then Claim 1 is easy to check and is right.

Thanks in advance for pointing out my mistake if any.

Comment: no need to invoke Jordan blocks, tho yes, it is good to see Jordan chains here. the key trick in all this sort of material is: iterate by $T$. so suppose $c_1v+c_2Tv+c_3T^2v=0$. then multiplication by $T$ gives $c_1Tv+c_2T^2v=0$. iterating again gives $c_1T^2v=0$. can you take it from here?

Comment: @symplectomorphic Thank you! That hint is big enough! So both of the claims are right.

Comment: Claim 1 is true because root subspaces corresponding to different eigenvalues are in direct sum.